# How does one separate log data sent to a remote rsyslog server?

Tags: logging, ubuntu-14.04, syslog, rsyslog

I have messages from multiple apache2 web servers logging to a rsyslog server.  I've used a template to separate each `/var/log/syslog` file into its own folder based off of the ip address of the server

**From my rsyslog server**

```
#/etc/rsyslog.conf
$template FILENAME,"/var/log/%fromhost-ip%/syslog.log"
```

Later, I decided to add more logs to the logging.

**From one of my web servers**

```
#/etc/rsyslog.conf
$ModLoad imfile
$InputFileName /var/log/customFile.log
$InputFileTag custom-log
$InputFileStateFile myfile
$InputFileSeverity info
$InputFileFacility local3
$InputFilePollInterval 1
$InputFilePersistStateInterval 1
$InputRunFileMonitor
local3.* @@192.168.1.20:514
```

Now, as expected, the logs from `/var/log/customFile.log` are going to the rsyslog server in `/var/log/192.168.1.x/syslog.log`.

What I'd like to happen is ALSO have those logs go to a separate file.  So, on my rsyslog server, I'd like my `/var/log/192.168.1.x/` directory to still have a syslog.log file, with all logs from that server, but also have a customLog.log file that is just the logs from the imfile info from /var/log/customFile.log

Is there any way to separate this out once it's on the rsyslog server?